# Create EAR Project With SpringBoot module

Tags: spring-boot, maven, ear

I need to create an `EAR` file to be deployed on `JBoss EAP 7`. I considered to build a project structure like the following:

```
- rootproject
  -- ear (ear)
  -- web (war)
```

Therefore for the `rootproject` I have created a new Simple Maven project (using Eclipse 06/2020), with the following `.pom.xml`:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
 <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
 <groupId>jboss_test</groupId>
 <artifactId>jboss_test</artifactId>
 <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
 <packaging>pom</packaging>
 <name>jboss_ear_test</name>

 <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.11.RELEASE</version>
 </parent>

 <profiles>
  <profile>
    <id>default</id>
    <activation>
        <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
    </activation>
    <modules>
        <module>ear</module>
        <module>web</module>
    </modules>
  </profile>
 </profiles>

</project>
```

Therefore, inside it, I have created a `SpringBoot 2.2.11` project (WEB) with the following `.pom.xml`:

```
....
....
<parent>
    <artifactId>jboss_test</artifactId>
    <groupId>jboss_test</groupId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>

<artifactId>web</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<name>web-test</name>
<description>Spring Boot JBOSS</description>

.... // some dependencies
```

And a Maven module used the ear with the following `.pom.xml`:

```
....
....
<parent>
    <artifactId>jboss_test</artifactId>
    <groupId>jboss_test</groupId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>

<artifactId>ear</artifactId>
<packaging>ear</packaging>
<name>ear-test</name>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <configuration>
                <finalName>JBOSS-TEST_EAR</finalName>
                <version>6</version>
                <defaultLibBundleDir>lib</defaultLibBundleDir>
                <modules>
                    <webModule>
                        <groupId>jboss_test</groupId>
                        <artifactId>web</artifactId>
                        <bundleFileName>JBOSS-TEST.war</bundleFileName>
                        <contextRoot>/TEST</contextRoot>
                    </webModule>
                </modules>
           </configuration>
      </plugin>
   </plugins>
</build>
```

When I try to build the project from its root I obtain the following error:

```
Artifact[war:jboss_test:web] is not a dependency of the project
```

Can you help me to find out whats wrong??

Thank you

Comment: As the message is telling you that problem. You don't have defined the web part being a dependency of the ear project... apart from that I strongly recommend to remove the profile from your pom with the modules it makes no sense nor is there something useful in relationship with modules/profiles...

Comment: And how can I achieve this??

Comment: Add the dependency into your pom of the web module...

Comment: I try it but I obtain more errors, can you write two line of code?? I want to create an EAR that contains my web .war package... why I have to declare the ear inside pom of war project?

Comment: Define the dependency in your `<artifactId>ear</artifactId>` module not in the war.. neither the ear inside pom of the war project..

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot to @khmarbaise for his response, I solved as follows:

Creating `rootproject` as Simple Maven project, `.pom.xml`:

```
<groupId>it.coding.jboss.deployment</groupId>
<artifactId>jbdeployment</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>

<parent>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
  <version>2.2.11.RELEASE</version>
  <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<modules>
 <module>ear-test</module>
 <module>web-test</module>
</modules>
```

Creating `ear-test` as Maven module, `.pom.xml`:

```
<parent>
  <groupId>it.coding.jboss.deployment</groupId>
  <artifactId>jbdeployment</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>

<artifactId>ear-test</artifactId>
<packaging>ear</packaging>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <configuration>
                <finalName>TEST-EAR</finalName>
                <version>6</version>
                <defaultLibBundleDir>lib</defaultLibBundleDir>
                <modules>
                    <webModule>
                        <groupId>it.coding.jboss.deployment</groupId>
                        <artifactId>web-test</artifactId>
                        <bundleFileName>WEB-TEST.war</bundleFileName>
                        <contextRoot>/WEB-TEST</contextRoot>
                    </webModule>
                </modules>
                <archive>
                    <addMavenDescriptor>false</addMavenDescriptor>
                    <manifestEntries>
                         <Implementation-Title>JBOSS-TEST</Implementation-Title>
                         <Implementation-Version>1.0</Implementation-Version>
                         <Implementation-Vendor>CODING</Implementation-Vendor>
                         <Built-By></Built-By>
                    </manifestEntries>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>it.coding.jboss.deployment</groupId>
        <artifactId>web-test</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <type>war</type>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Creating `web-test` as `SpringBoot 2.2.11` project, `.pom.xml`:

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <parent>
     <groupId>it.coding.jboss.deployment</groupId>
     <artifactId>jbdeployment</artifactId>
     <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>

  <artifactId>web-test</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <name>web-test</name>
  <description>Spring Boot JBOSS</description>

  <properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
     // dependencies
  </dependencies>
  ...
  ...
</project>
```

Maven build goes fine and EAR is created.. Than I would like to ask one more thing: do you think I have to define all the dependecies inside my `ear-test` pom?? Also those of the `web-test` project related to `Spring`, `Hibernate` etc.. ?

Thanks a lot